# React HOC to handle clicks outside a given Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-functions

I desire to make a Higher Order Component to manage outside clicks. When it is determined that a user has clicked outside a given component a certain passed function should execute. This HOC takes 2 parameters:

- **BoundaryComponent**: the component we are interested in determining if clicks are outside of it
- **onOutsideClick**: a function to execute when a click occurs outside the component

This **ClickOutside** component looks like:

```
import React from 'react'
const { Component } = React
import { findDOMNode } from 'react-dom'

export default function ClickOutside (BoundaryComponent, onOutsideClick) {
    return class Wrapper extends Component {
        constructor (props) {
            super(props)
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick.bind(this), true)
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
            document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClick.bind(this), true)
        }

        render () {
            const props = Object.assign({}, this.props, { ref: this.getContainer.bind(this) })
            return (
                <BoundaryComponent
                    {...props}
                />
            )
        }

        getContainer (wrapped) {
            this.container = findDOMNode(wrapped)
        }

        handleClick(e) {
            if (this.container && !this.container.contains(e.target) && typeof onOutsideClick === 'function') {
                onOutsideClick()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I am trying to utilize this component like this:

```
import React from 'react'
const { ClickOutside } = 'utils/click-outside'
import { updatePicklistActiveIndex } from 'components/store/actions'
import { getPicklistActiveIndex } from 'components/store/selectors'
import PickList from 'components/picklist'

// ...

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
    return {
        updatePicklistActiveIndex: (activeIndex) => { dispatch(updatePicklistActiveIndex(activeIndex)) },
    }
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
    return {
        picklistActiveIndex: getPicklistActiveIndex(state),
    }
}

let onOutsideClick = null // This feels like a code smell

class DropdownPickList extends PickList {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            dropdownVisible: false,
        }
        onOutsideClick = () => {
            this.props.updatePicklistActiveIndex(-1)
            this.setState({ dropdownVisible: false })
        }
    }

    // ...

    render() {
        return (
            //...jsx to render DropdownPickList
        )
    }
}
const pickList = ClickOutside(DropdownPickList, () => { onOutsideClick() })
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(pickList)
```

The above implementation works as I would expect...

But defining `onOutsideClick` outside the context of the DropdownPickList Class, and then overwriting this variable reference within the constructor of this Class just feels wrong. But it seems to be the only way to get access to the props and state within the class needed to close the dropdown.

I also tried using a static method in the DropdownPickList class to handle the onOutsideClick, but the problem with this is this Class is passed as an unrendered component, so I do not have access to any of its instance methods in my handleClick of the HOC.

There must be a better way to do this? Any help or alternative implementation ideas/patterns would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a function, just export the wrapper and change as the following :

- BoundaryComponent :  move to be the children of the wrapper (so it will be actually a wrapper) like so :

  ```
  <Wrapper>
      <BoundaryComponent />
  <Wrapper>
  ```

While inside wrapper you will render {this.props.children}

- onOutsideClick: the onOutsideClick function move to the props of `Wrapper` :

  ```
  <Wrapper onOutsideClick={this.onOutsideClick}>
      <BoundaryComponent />
  <Wrapper>
  ```